# Best practice and structure for component that includes another component inside

Tags: angularjs, components

I use Angular v1.3.7, and i want to create a master component that can handle anothers component inside.

`<rl-data-master>
    <rl-grid>
       <rl-toolbar>
       </rl-toolbar>
    </rl-grid>
    <rl-form>
       <rl-toolbar>
       </rl-toolbar>
    </rl-form>
 </rl-data-master>`

each component have a view, but with component's view i want to display another component's view. Example: `<rl-grid></rl-grid>` displays a grid, but with this structure i want to display grid AND a toolbar.

Simple example of component:

`var rlDataMaster = {
    templateUrl: 'RL.DataMaster.tml.html',
    bindings: {
        options: '=',
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
    }
}
rlDataMaster.$inject = ['$scope'];`

And

`DashboardApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $templateCache.put('RL.DataMaster.tml.html',
       '<div>blabla</div>'
    );
}`

And in my html

`<rl-data-master>
    inside
 </rl-data-master>`

**In this simple example in my page, the view i get is 'blabla', and the text 'inside' never show up.**

I want to create an independencies components, `<rl-toolbar options="toolbarOptions"></rl-toolbar>` must take as argument a toolbarOptions and inherit form parent.

I also want this `<rl-toolbar></rl-toolbar>` can stand alone, or with different parent

`<rl-data-master>
    <rl-toolbar>
    </rl-toolbar>
    <rl-grid>
    </rl-grid>
 </rl-data-master>`

Where can find the better structure or practice for this purpose?

**EDIT**
from answer i use `'<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'` and works, but how can include more child component in different ''' '?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transclusion` in this case, where you can project the inner content of `rl-data-master` directive to be projected on the transcluded element mentioned inside directive. [*Transclusion can be achieve via server ways*](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/transclusion/), but here I'm demonstrating the usage using `ng-transclude` directive. Also mention `transclude: true` inside `rl-data-master` directive.

So your directive template could change to below

```
$templateCache.put('RL.DataMaster.tml.html',
   '<div>'+
      'blabla'+
      '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'+
   '</div>'
);
```

Comment: yeah works! Also, how can first compontn to have acccess to other child compontns?

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket look at the [require API](https://toddmotto.com/directive-to-directive-communication-with-require/) of directive

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket does it helped?